# Vue and Vuetify Animation Content Jump

Tags: javascript, animation, vuejs2, css-animations, vuetify.js

When the Vue animation ends the content "jumps" back up as you can see in this example:

https://codepen.io/propsoft/pen/PRYjBZ

```
<transition name="slide-y-transition">
  <div v-show="compare">
    Here is the hidden {{ content }}
  </div>
</transition name="slide-y-transition">
```

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the animation is that it uses `transform: translateY(-15px);`, which causes only a visual translation of the content but the div is still occupying the same space. One way to fix that is to animate other properties, like `height` for example. The drawback with that is that the div needs to have a fixed height, which may not be possible in all situations.

You can test different approaches without animating anything, see what causes the div below to actually be displaced or not. And then you can animate that.

Check out this codepen with your example animated using `height`: https://codepen.io/noeldemartin/pen/ommxZG

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation :)